# Android Studio: Генерация textView

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

Ребят, помогите, в общем...
Нужно в цикле реализовать создание нескольких TextView и поместить их в конкретный LinearLayout(с индексом)
Так же у каждого созданного объекта должен быть свой id 
Не знаю как это толково сделать, в ютубе не нашел
Если попроще, то нужно сгенерировать несколько объектов(текст) и закинуть последовательно в LinearLayout, назначив каждому свой id
Не поможете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<TextView> txt = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  TextView txtItem = new TextView(context);
  txt.add(txtItem);
  linearLayout.addView(txtItem);
}
```

Comment: А что принимает TextView(context) ?

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: Что нужно писать вместо context, что там должно быть?

Comment: Обычно this, если вызов идёт из Activity класса